# JPA/Hibernate how to get N items of each category

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

Let's assume we have the following Car entity in a database: ID, Name, Model.

I want to retrieve N Cars of each Model. For brevity sake, if we have the following Models: BMW, Porche, Volkswagen, I want to get 2 BMW, 2 Porche, and 2 Volkswagen.

Is this achievable through either a single HQL or an SQL Query ?

The best I've achieved so far is using 3 separate queries for each model.

Comment: HQL is not suitable for this type of query. Some analytical SQL could be helpful. Tell us what database you're using (oracle, mssql, ...)?

Comment: I'm using a mysql database. I'm not hell bent on using HQL for this, I just need it to be as fast as possible. I've tried with UNION with plain SQL as Stijn suggested and it works decently, however I'm still exploring other options.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.

Even with plain SQL you would have to use a UNION to accomplish this and this is not supported in HQL.

What you could do is create a VIEW (for the UNION) and map this to Car entity.

http://timezra.blogspot.de/2009/05/mapping-hibernate-entities-to-views.html